# Perform convolution between two functions

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, fourier-transform, signal-processing

I'm trying to solve:

> Find the fourier transform of performing mask $h(x,y)=\text{sinc}(x)\cdot\text{sinc}(y)$ on the image:
> $$
> f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
> 1 & 0\leq|x|,|y|<0.5\\
> 0 & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$

What I did - We need to calculate $g(x,y)=f(x,y)\star h(x,y)$ and then find the fourier transform of $G(x,y)$. We will find the fourier transform of $f(x,y)$:
$$
\begin{align*}
F(u,v)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)e^{i2\pi(ux+vy)}dxdy\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{I}_{\left\{ 0\leq|x|,|y|<0.5\right\} }e^{i2\pi(ux+vy)}dxdy\\&=\int_{-0.5}^{0.5}\int_{-0.5}^{0.5}e^{i2\pi(ux+vy)}dxdy\\&=\int_{-0.5}^{0.5}e^{i2\pi ux}dx\int_{-0.5}^{0.5}e^{i2\pi vy}dy
\end{align*}
$$
We know that $\int_{a}^{b}e^{i2\pi ux}dx=\frac{i\left(e^{i2\pi au}-e^{i2\pi bu}\right)}{2\pi u}$ so we get:
$$
\int_{-0.5}^{0.5}e^{i2\pi ux}dx=\frac{i\left(e^{i2\pi0.5u}-e^{i2\pi(-0.5)u}\right)}{2\pi u}=\frac{i\left(e^{i\pi u}-e^{-i\pi u}\right)}{2\pi u}
$$
We will use that $\sin\theta=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}\right)$ so we get:
$$
e^{i\pi u}-e^{-i\pi u}=2i\left(\sin\left(\pi u\right)\right)
$$
In total, we get:
$$
\int_{-0.5}^{0.5}e^{i2\pi ux}dx=\frac{i\left(e^{i\pi u}-e^{-i\pi u}\right)}{2\pi u}=\frac{i2i\left(\sin\left(\pi u\right)\right)}{2\pi u}=-\frac{\sin\left(\pi u\right)}{\pi u}=-\text{sinc}(u)
$$
So:
$$
F(u,v)=\int_{-0.5}^{0.5}e^{i2\pi ux}dx\int_{-0.5}^{0.5}e^{i2\pi vy}dy=\left(-\text{sinc}(u)\right)\left(-\text{sinc}(v)\right)=\text{sinc}(u)\text{sinc}(v)
$$
This means that the fourier transform of $f(x,y)$ is $\text{sinc}(u)\text{sinc}(v)$:
$$
h(u,v)=\text{sinc}(u)\text{sinc}(v)=\Im\left\{ f(x,y)\right\} 
$$
From the Duality theorm we know that if the fourier transform of $f(x,y)$ is $F(u,v)$ then the fourier transform of $F(-u,-v)$ is $f(x,y)$. So we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x,y)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(-u,-v)e^{i2\pi\left((-u)x+(-v)y\right)}dudv\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\text{sinc}(-u)\text{sinc}(-v)e^{i2\pi\left((-u)x+(-v)y\right)}dudv\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\text{sinc}(u)\text{sinc}(v)e^{-i2\pi\left(ux+vy\right)}dudv
\end{align*}
$$
This means that we get:
$$
f(x,y)=\Im\left\{ \text{sinc}(u)\text{sinc}(v)\right\} =\Im\left\{ h(u,v)\right\} 
$$
Now I'm trying to use the convolution theorem. For 1 diminution:

> if $y(t)=f(t)\star h(t)$ then $\hat{y}(f)=\hat{x}(f)\hat{g}(f)$ and if $h(t)=g(t)\cdot k(t)$ then $\hat{h}(f)=\hat{g}(f)\star\hat{k}(f)$.

Now we have $g(x,y)=f(x,y)\star h(x,y)$ so we get:
$$
g(x,y)=f(x,y)\star h(x,y)=\Im\left\{ h(u,v)\right\} \star\Im\left\{ f(u,v)\right\} 
$$
From the convolution theorem we get:
$$
G(u,v)=h(u,v)\cdot f(u,v)=\text{sinc}(u)\text{sinc}(v)\cdot f(u,v)
$$
Is it possible to check my solution?